# React Native ListView append on top without losing the current scroll position

Tags: listview, react-native

We are looking for a way to achieve the following with React Native's ListView:

We have a `feed` of posts and want to fetch newer posts in the background and then append them on top of the ListView, however we would want to keep the current scroll position somehow (~ as in the user still sees the same, just that he has newer posts on top if he scrolls on top).

What we do right now is simply change the `dataSource` like this `dataSource={this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.posts)}` but this may lead to a jump in the list view (different post will be visible).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: No, not really. :) What we did in the end was to pull from the server if we had updates (but not add them to the dataSource) and in case we had new posts, we rendered an overlay with a caption like "new posts" on top of the list view. When the user clicked it we would change the dataSource and immediately scroll to the top of the list view. Not sure if there would be a nicer way to do it today (haven't worked with React Native for some months now).